# Change Uibutton font size based on selection state

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I know that we can button font size by below statement.

```
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)

button.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.white, forState: .selected)
button.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.clear, forState: .normal)
```

I have made an extenstion of setting backgroundcolor.

Is there anyway i can do same for font size.

The thing is that I have multiple button and want to know if this type of approach is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. Call `setAttributedTitle(_:for:)` for your different states. The attributed title includes font and size information

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624012-setattributedtitle

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific method or property to change the font of `UIButton`. However, we can change it in the button action method like below.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SELECT_FONT", size: "SELECT_FONT_SIZE")
    } else {
        sender.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "YOUR_FONT", size: "FONT_SIZE")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a very "weird" way that I usually do, that is add a UILabel inside the UIButton, as UIButton inherit from UIView, so you can easy add UILabel inside, with the configured font, the only thing that you will need to align, but you can easy use anchor to this. Will work like a charm, you can even create a extension for this like

```
extension: UIButton {
    func addCustomFont() {
        // Implementation, like self.addSubview( < UILabel >)
    }
}
```